# How to write text in one column only in double column with second column for margins only

Tags: multicol

I am trying to create a two column book class document in which the two columns are separated by a dotted vertical lines. The first column should be the main column used for all text, figures and equations. However, occasionally second column will be used for marginal notes. The second column may contain dotted lines with interline separation of 8mm. This is what I have made so far but it lacks several desired features.

````
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.25in}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{2pt}
\makeatletter
\def\columnseprulecolor\vrule\@width\columnseprule{%
    \vbox to \ht\mult@rightbox{\leaders\vbox{\kern2pt\hbox{.}\kern2pt}\vfill}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}[\chapter{My Chapter Number One. Long chapter title}]
        
        \section{Long section name. There is nothing I can think of to put here.}
        
        \lipsum
        \begin{equation}
            E = m \times c^2
        \end{equation}  
        \lipsum
        \begin{equation}
            E = m \times c^2
        \end{equation}
                \clearpage
    \end{multicols}
    
\end{document} ```
````

Comment: Documentclass book already contains a marginpar area, which can be enlarged using geometry.  You can write in it using \marginpar or \marginnote (you can't use \marginpar inside a float).  I recommend the marginfix package to avoid overruns.

Comment: You might consider using paracol to create a two column layout and ignore (replace) the marginpar area.  The separating line has been asked before.

Comment: How can I force LaTeX to  write text on, say, leftmost column only?

Comment: With paracol EVERYTHING goes into one column until you use \switchcolumn or \switchcolumn*.   The columns do not have to be the same width either.